# Track if visitor come from adwords or organic

Tags: php

In PHP I want to track if visitors come from AdWords or via Organic. I tried it with HTTP_REFERER but then I only got https://www.google.com.

Is there a way to find out if visitors come via AdWords or Organic and if possible how to get keyword?

Comment: Yes, AdWords API: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/index

Comment: @VladPreda, thanks for your answer. I will look into that. It's that the only way to do?

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen Technically, it might not be the only way but it's the cleanest and most reliable.